# Make a bootable USB for Ubuntu

Tags: usb, live-usb, live-environment

I want to run Ubuntu from a USB stick. Not the installer. The actual OS. I want to be able to run Ubuntu at home with my drive then go to my friend's and start it up there and have all my files saved. Kind of like a portable computer. I have a Mac and a Sandisk 16 GB drive. I really want to do this. Thanks

Comment: There is no difference between the installation media and live media for Ubuntu. Just download the Ubuntu ISO and make a bootable USB disk with Unetbootin. You can enable persistence which is essentially a way to keep your saved changes (like software installed, documents, etc). http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu. Check the link

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create another liveUSB, not the one where you want to install it.

Boot from it while having the other one connected as well. Once in the live desktop environment open **Disks** and check  the path of the drive you want Ubuntu on (/dev/sdb for example).

Launch the installation and then make sure you select the **something else** option.

Choose the correct drive where to install and create the partition table you wish. I suggest three partitions:

1. Ubuntu
2. Swap
3. Fat partition for documents (to share with Windows)

You may opt not to have this third one if you do not need to share files.

When you're asked for the installation of the bootloader, make sure you select `/dev/sd?`, where ? is your installation media.

That's it.

Comment: The FAT32 partition should be the first partition as Windows can only see the first partition on a flash drive.